# Preview binary data from database in new tab in browser before downloading

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a code in ASP.NET C# where I am able to retrieve binary data from database and also able to download it on click. Now I want to preview this data be it doc,pdf,image or any format in a new tab in browser, just like gmail does, before downloading. I have tried many codes but unable to achieve exactly what I am willing. My code to download is as below:-

```
 public void DownloadFile(string FileName, string message_id)
{
    byte[] bytes;
    string fileName, contentType;

    Session["message_id"] = message_id;
    con.Close();
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from FilesContent where (FileName='" + FileName + "' AND message_id='" + message_id + "')", con);

    using (SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader())
    {
        sdr.Read();
        bytes = (byte[])sdr["FileContent"];
        contentType = sdr["FileExtension"].ToString();
        fileName = sdr["FileName"].ToString();
    }
    con.Close();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);

}
```

Secondly,I tried to put this download code in the page load event of a new page named "ViewFiles.aspx" and tried to redirect to this particular page in a new tab using the following code:-

```
 Response.Write("<script> window.open( '" + "ViewFiles.aspx" + "','_blank' ); </script>");
    Response.End();
```

But I am unable to achieve what I want. I want this binary file from database to get converted to whatever format it is and need this to be previewed in browser just like gmail before download.

Comment: The way you write your SQL command ("FileName='" + FileName + "' AND message_id='" + message_id + "'") is very risky and can be open to SQL injection attacks. Use SQL command parameters instead

Comment: "unable to achieve" - what specifically happens and what should happen? When you put file data into the response stream, you're very dependent on how each individual client browser handles the various files.

Comment: Basically I get a pop up kind of window which usually appears when downloading that ask for open or save option. That means a user has to download it first to view it. I want to view this file in the browser itself rather than making download option a compulsion to view the file.

Comment: How do you want the "Preview" to be? An Image of the first page? A google docs link?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you write in your controller will always force a download. You could create a second page without where you do not force the download via headers and instead "display" the content and add a download button calling the method you created.

But as some commenters already said, while it works with images, depending on the browser and the software installed, you can not "preview" pdfs ord docs since some installed programm takes over.

One solution might be to add a description/preview-image to each entry and display that along with a download-button.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is is to write your own previewer page. On your page, where the user can select which file to preview, should be links, like this:

```
<a href="preview.aspx?id=1" target="_blank">File1.jpg</a>
<a href="preview.aspx?id=2" target="_blank">File2.jpg</a>
<a href="preview.aspx?id=3" target="_blank">File3.png</a>
```

Now your `preview.aspx` page should just have an [ASP.NET literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control on the form. The code behind will use this to render your preview.

In your code behind, query your SQL server and figure out what kind of file it is. You can figure out what kind of file it is by either looking at the extension and getting the MIME type or using the "magic numbers" method.

Once you know what kind of file it is, create a preview contingency appropriate for that kind of file. For example, if its an image file, your code could look like this:

```
private void CreatePreview(string mimeType, string file)
{
    if (mimeType.ToLower() == "image/jpeg" || mimeType.ToLower() == "image/png")
    {
        literal1.Text = literal1.Text + "<img src=\"" + file + "\" />";
    }
}
```

If the file is a text file, your code might look like this:

```
private void CreatePreview(string mimeType, string file)
{
    if (mimeType.ToLower() == "image/jpeg" || mimeType.ToLower() == "image/png")
    {
        literal1.Text = literal1.Text + "<img src=\"" + file + "\" />";
    } else if (mimeType.ToLower() == "text/plain")
    {
        literal1.Text = literal1.Text + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(File.ReadAllText(file));
    }
}
```

Hopefully you get the idea! You'll not want to use this code directly, how it is. You'll want to pretty it up and make Ajax-ify it in order to give the user a good experience.